# How to create a status in Microsoft Teams and apply for all company?

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams

community! I'm a member of the IT Department, and our management has requested the creation of a new status labeled 'WFH' (Work from Home), with the designated color being blue. The objective is to enable all employees to have their WFH days reflected in the system, automatically turning their status blue during these work-from-home days. Do you believe this is achievable? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to write a [mcve], then [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). As written, this question is off-topic here: there's no programming question, and it's just a requirement.

Comment: Microsoft Teams is already having an option to set your location to Home/Remote - https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Gods.png. This can be set only using Teams UI, there is no way to set this programmatically. You can suggest this at https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472